# NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined. Cant figure out correct code

Tags: r, reticulate

Error: NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined.

```
history <- model %>% fit(
  train_generator,
  steps_per_epoch = 100,
  epochs = 30,
  validation_data = validation_generator,
  validation_steps = 50
)
```

Installed Libraries keras, tensorflow, reticulate

Cant figure out how to correct code in RStudio

[image]

Comment: Well, the traceback info suggests you never installed the necessary  **python** libraries.

Comment: What python library do I need?